# Related questions are closed

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, closing

I'm noticing that some of the 'related questions' on the right hand side of the screen are closed ones. Could we filter those out? We obviously don't want to be drawing people's attention to them.

Comment: This would be a good question for [meta.SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) as well!

Answer (score 1):

[Related Questions Include Closed Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14614/related-questions-include-closed-questions)